# Google drive add meta data to file

Tags: google-drive-api, google-drive-realtime-api

I would like to use the googledrive api to search for files. I would like to add metadata to it.

```
    Example:

    File: computers1.pdf
    Brand: brand1

    File: computers2.pdf
    Brand: brand2

    File: computers3.doc
    Brand: brand2
```

As you can see the file names aren't usefull to search for a certain brand. There are many files so renaming them all is hard and sometimes a file can have multiple 'brands'.

Is there a way to add custom metadata to the file/index of google. In this example it would be to get all the files from brand: x.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not currently possible with the Drive API, but we understand your use case and we are already considering implementing something that will help you with that. Please stay tuned!

For the moment, you might want to use the `description` field to store your metadata and perform searches on that.

Another important thing to mention is that Google Drive will automatically index the text from PDFs, so you can already search for those values if they are included in the document body.

Comment: Google drive will only index the first 100 pages of a (pdf)file?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/drive/search-parameters I can't find how to search on the description... It seems that description is just seen as fullText???

Comment: Yes, fullText includes title, description and content.

Comment: It's been a year and a half, have things changed?

Comment: @zneak : checkout the properties tag. You can add Key and Values into that while inserting/updating the file. Check https://developers.google.com/drive/web/search-parameters. This may help you.

Comment: @Kartik are those custom file properties searchable (via regular users) in the web ui? (assuming the property is "PUBLIC")

Comment: @Claudio Cherubino Is there anything other than "description", which is not visible in the Drive UI.