# Can I use indexable text to store meta data in a Google drive document?

Tags: google-drive-api

When uploading a file to Google Drive I would maintain a reference to the original file with the document in Google. There is a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12093934/google-drive-add-meta-data-to-file) about meta-data, but I would like to know if I can use one of the two new properties in the new API. The reference would be a 32 character key, and I need to be able to find the document using that key.

[Indexable text](http://javadoc.google-api-java-client.googlecode.com/hg/apis/drive/v2/index.html) seems to be an option, I can store the key there and use a search to retrieve the document. However, if the key is in any other document I have the risk getting multiple hits

[OriginalFilename](http://javadoc.google-api-java-client.googlecode.com/hg/apis/drive/v2/index.html) is a property that I can set, but I am not sure If I can search for that property.

I am going to try to use a combination, write the key to the indexable text and in the original file name, so I can search for the file and pick the right one using the original file name to pick the right one if I get multiple matches.

This seems a bit of a hack, is there a better way, or any reason why this approach will fail?

[Google drive add meta data to file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12093934/google-drive-add-meta-data-to-file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can *technically* use the two fields, but they are meant for different purposes and there's no guarantee the user or other applications won't change their values.

As written in the other question you mention, we are already working on something that will address your use case, so please bear with us a bit more and you'll have a better solution. Thanks!